# How to use common source code across multiple IntelliJ projects?

Tags: java, android, intellij-idea

I'm currently looking to start two new projects using IntelliJ - one which is an Android project and another that is just a standard Java project.

I want to use a lot of the same code within both projects, but don't want to copy files into projects. At a later stage, it is likely that this code will be used in other projects too.

At the moment I'm having difficulty working out how to include the common code within both projects - I have created new modules but then it seems that the import does not recognize code from the module.

Therefore the structure of directories would be something like:

```
|- Android Project
|- Java Project
|- Android Library
|- Java Library
|- Common Library
```

So you would have:

- "Android Project" uses code from "Android Library" and "Common Library" directories
- "Java Project" uses code from "Java Library" and "Common Library" directories
- "Android Library" uses code from "Common Library" directory
- "Java Library" uses code from "Common Library" directory

Could someone please advise as to how this is to be configured in IntelliJ?

In the case of the Android project, I am playing around with the module settings and dependencies and can get it to work briefly, but then these changes get lost whenever there is a Gradle sync.

Thanks.

Comment: Create a library project containing the common code and reference it from your other projects.

Answer (score 1):

What you're probably looking for is a structure that utilizes a project of modules. (very much like Visual Studio solutions).

You may usually create a [project](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/about-projects.html) in Intellij. But that project can have many [modules](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/about-modules.html).

To set it up, I would start by adding an empty project. After you create the empty project start adding modules. Once you have your modules in place, you'll need to add the module dependencies in the Project Structure settings.

1. Open the Structure settings dialogue
2. Click Modules
3. Select the module with one or more dependencies on other modules
4. Click on the Dependency tab
5. Click the green + sign on the right
6. Choose Module Dependency
7. Choose the module(s) to depend on

Read more about your options on the the [Dependency Tab](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/dependencies-tab.html).

Comment: Thanks Chief.  Yes it appears that Modules are the way to go, but I haven't been able to get them to work properly yet.  The only way has been creating a new module within the project directory and then copying the source code into the default "src" directory.

Doing it any other way, I find that if within the app (eg. MainActivity) I want to use a class that is in one of the modules, it cannot find it.

Comment: @CapitanoKyz, no problem, see if the edits help you any.

Comment: @Capitano https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/intro_multi_project_builds.html

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions.  I have edited the original question with more detail on structures and dependencies.  The main issue seems to be that the dependencies get lost once there is a Gradle sync or re-import.